# SQL query over multiple inputs

Tags: sql, search, predicate

I've got table containing a number of text columns, and need to be able to query the table using a search term. For single terms, this is simple...

```
SELECT * FROM things WHERE @searchTerm in (column1, column2...columnX)
```

However, sometimes I need to search over multiple terms in a single query, something like...

```
SELECT * FROM things WHERE @searchTerms in (column1, column2...columnX)
```

...where `@searchTerms` is a collection of values, rather than a single value. Is there a way to emulate this behaviour in SQL?

UPDATE:
Thank you @Tedo G., unfortunately I need the query to use `AND` between the different terms. To do that I've added a change to yours to group the results and ensure the count per distinct result matches the number of terms...

```
SELECT 
     * 
FROM 
     things AS A INNER JOIN @searchTerms AS B
          ON B.[FieldName] IN (column1, column2...columnX)
     GROUP BY column1, column2...columnX
     HAVING count(column1) = @numberOfSearchTerms
```

...this works, but is there a better way?

Comment: You should probably look into the full text search capabilities of the database you are using.

Comment: That's probably what I'm going to do, but I'd like to know if there is a way to do it without using full text search, if possible

Comment: Put the @searchTerms values in a temporary table?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? (Postgres? Oracle?, ...)

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other way to achieve this is to make a table variable and fill it with your search term values, then join it :

```
SELECT 
     * 
FROM 
     things AS A INNER JOIN @searchTerms AS B
          ON B.[FieldName] IN (column1, column2...columnX)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but I need the query to use `AND` between terms rather than `OR`, I've updated my question